# I can't add System Tray into the panel in kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, system-tray

I've tried to add the System Tray widget into the panel bar, but when I double click it nothing happens.

```
$ uname -vrpmios

Linux 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ plasmashell --version

plasmashell 5.12.9

$ kf5-config --version

Qt: 5.9.5
KDE Frameworks: 5.47.0
kf5-config: 1.0

$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2353 set 12  2019 plasma.desktop

$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
plasma

$ ls /usr/bin/*session
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session

$ head ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
[Containments][1]
activityId=4a35535f-6618-447a-ba7d-568df58dbc5a
formfactor=0
immutability=1
lastScreen=0
location=0
plugin=org.kde.plasma.folder
wallpaperplugin=org.kde.image

[Containments][1][Configuration]
```